# jQuery: JSON object children handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to make a `<table>` through a javascript function.

I'm getting a JSON element that looks like that :

```
header
    ["Nom", "Région", "Activité", 10 more...]
0   "Nom"   
1   "Région"
2   "Activité"
// other fields 

body
    Object { entity0=[13], entity1=[13], entity2=[13], more...}

entity0
    ["Org2", "Org2", "Org2", 10 more...]

0    "Org2"
1    "Org2" 
2    "Org2"
//Other fields
entity1
    ["gfhu", "rtyud", "dgud", 10 more...]
//Other entities
```

And I'm trying to decode it like that (I parse the JSON and give it to that function) :

```
function createTableEntity(tab, id){
    table = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="'+id+'">';
    table = table + '<thead><tr>';
    $(tab.header).children().each(function(){
        table = table + '<td>' + this + '</td>';
    });
    table = table + '</tr></thead>';

    table = table + '<tbody>';

    $(tab.body).children().each(function(){
        table = table + '<tr>';

       $(this).children().each(function(){
           table = table + '<td>' + $(this) + '</td>';
       });

       table = table + '</tr>';
    });

    table = table + '</tbody>';

    table = table + '</table>';

    //alert(table);

    return table;
}
```

From the results I have, there are no children (`$(tab.header).children().each(function(){});`).

Where does it come from? How do I loop through the elements parsed from JSON?

Comment: Try to parse the JSON object inside the function.

Comment: As I said, I did parse it before and give it as an argument. `tab` is parsed JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jquery to loop through the result of a JSON parsing as it's a Javascript object.

If you have an array in tab.header, you simply can loop on it with

```
  $.each(tab.header, function() {
```

Or more classicaly, without jquery, using

```
 for (var i=0; i<tab.header.length; i++) {
```